# Can I change iCloud ID

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud, apple-id

I originally created an Apple ID for use on the App Store in iTunes.
When Apple introduced iCloud my Apple ID ended up being used.

I would like to separate these. I don't want to lose my app purchases (which I would like to share with family), so creating a new iCloud ID seems the best option.
I can't find any method of changing. Is this possible?

I assume if I create a new iCloud ID it would need to resynch everything.

Comment: If you set up [Family Sharing](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060) your family could share your apps & songs, if they wished, but wouldn't get your messages, etc. You keep your ID, make them all get their own, linked. [I've had many years of multiple IDs, as my first was long before iCloud etc ever existed & you couldn't use one for both back then. I really wouldn't recommend it if you can avoid it.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't have to be the same. Sign out of iCloud in Settings and set up the new Apple ID. Then, if that Apple ID's also been applied to the stores, go to one of them, sign out, and sign back in with your store Apple ID.

Source: My own experience - my iPod Touch works fine with my own Apple ID for iCloud and my family's Apple ID for the stores.

Comment: I tried signing out of iCloud on my Mac, unfortunately it deleted all my Calendar entries. (I logged on again, and got them back)

Comment: At least on a Mac, you can sign into multiple iCloud accounts. Sign into your primary one (for syncing everything) through the iCloud preference pane, and sign into the secondary one (for getting Mail and Calendars and other such stuff while keeping the rest of iCloud on your primary account) through the Internet Accounts pane.

Comment: I have created a secondary iCloud account on my Mac (after some time fighting with Apple about its stupid security questions). I will try, and see how this works.